Cancel function
I have a component on the search page, and inside the component, there is a useEffect that triggers the post filtering and fetching code from the database when the search words (city, word in post, number of posts) change. When I enter a word and then delete it, the code continues to run. If I enter another word, the two functions essentially run in parallel. I want to make it so that when a new word is entered or added, the previous filtering process is reset and started anew. For example, if I enter a word and the code starts (beginning to iterate through and filter posts), and then I immediately delete the word and add another one, the ongoing code stops and starts over with the new conditions.
React.useEffect(() =>  {
    const loadAndFilterPosts = async () => {
        let postsToLoad = 300; // first count posts for loading
        let allLoadedPosts:any = []; // array for all loading posts
        let filteredPosts= [];
        let keys:string[] = []; // keys from redis
        let i = 0;

      // if chosen category => get keys from refdis
      if (chosenCategory && chosenCategory.id) keys = await getKeys(chosenCategory?.id)

      while (allLoadedPosts.length < postsToLoad) {
          let newPosts = await loadPostsFromRedis(i, keys); // loading posts from Redis
          if (!newPosts.length) {
              break;
          }

          // if free period 
          if (infoUser && infoUser?.categoriesFreePeriod?.length > 0 && !infoUser?.endFreePeriod) {
              const currentDate = new Date();
              currentDate.setDate(currentDate.getDate() - 3);
              newPosts = newPosts.filter((item: any) => new Date(item.post_date_publish*1000).getTime() < currentDate.getTime());
          }

          allLoadedPosts = [...allLoadedPosts, ...newPosts];
          filteredPosts = applyFilters(allLoadedPosts); // add filter (keywords)

          setFilteredPosts(filteredPosts.sort((a:any, b:any) => a.data - b.data))
          if (filteredPosts.length >= postsToLoad) {
              break;
          }

          postsToLoad += 300;
          i++;
       }
   };
    loadAndFilterPosts()
    setPage(1)
}, [keyWords, keyCityWords, social, postsCount, chosenCategory])


React's useEffect hook can return a cleanup function. You can declare a local variable let abort = false at the first line of your useEffect and add a return () => {abort = true} at the end of useEffect hook. Add some ifs inside of your async function inside this useEffect and break execution in any way you want based on this variable state. Better way would be to use AbortController and pass the signal down to the used async functions, especially useful for api requests.

okay, thanks. It'works

Please see [ask], then revise your title to ask a clear, specific question.

The process you described is known as debouncing. You can use utils provided by underscore or lodash, but here is a custom example:
const runDebouncedSearch = useMemo(
  () => debounce((term: string) => searchSomething(term), 400),
  []
);

useEffect(() => {
  runDebouncedSearch(inputSearchTerm); // when input changes, schedule search in 400 ms. Cancel previous searches if typing rapidly
  return () => runDebouncedSearch.cancel(); // cancel pending searches, when detaching component
}, [runDebouncedSearch, inputSearchTerm]);

And implementation:
type DebounceOptions = XOR<
  { leading?: boolean },
  { leadingOnce?: boolean }
>;

export const debounce = <A = void>(
  func: (arg: A) => void,
  delay: number,
  { leading, leadingOnce }: DebounceOptions = {}
): CancellableFunction<A> => {
  let timerId: NodeJS.Timeout | undefined;
  let isLeadingRan = false;

  const debounced = (arg: A) => {
    const shouldRunLeadingOnce = leadingOnce && !isLeadingRan;
    const shouldRunLeading = leading || shouldRunLeadingOnce;

    if (!timerId && shouldRunLeading) {
      isLeadingRan = true;
      func(arg);
    }
    if (timerId) {
      clearTimeout(timerId);
    }

    timerId = shouldRunLeadingOnce
      ? undefined
      : setTimeout(() => func(arg), delay);
  };

  debounced.cancel = () => {
    timerId && clearTimeout(timerId);
    timerId = undefined;
  };

  return debounced;
};


What the OP described is not debouncing.
